# if statement inside mysql query to determine table to select

Tags: mysql

I would like to perform a **if statment** in the middle of a query, I need to find out if oc.product_type == 'clothing' or 'other' If it is clothing, then i need to select the **specific_clothing** table instead of the **non_clothing** table? I really lost with this one

```
SELECT o.total, o.shipping, o.order_date
      ,oc.product_type, oc.product_id, oc.quantity, oc.price_per
      ,cu.first_name, cu.last_name, CONCAT(cu.address1, cu.address2) AS address,
```

**//here is where im trying to use if**

```
  if(oc.product_type = 'clothing'
      SELECT style
        FROM specific_clothing
        where oc.product_id = specific_clothing_id) as item 

    FROM order_contents AS oc
    INNER JOIN `orders` as o ON oc.order_id = o.id
    INNER JOIN `customers` AS cu ON o.customer_id=cu.id
    WHERE o.customer_id = '214';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just looking at adding an outer join to `specific_clothing`. Something like this:

```
SELECT o.total, o.shipping, o.order_date
      ,oc.product_type, oc.product_id, oc.quantity, oc.price_per
      ,cu.first_name, cu.last_name, CONCAT(cu.address1, cu.address2) AS address
      ,sc.style AS item

    FROM order_contents AS oc
    INNER JOIN `orders` as o ON oc.order_id = o.id
    INNER JOIN `customers` AS cu ON o.customer_id=cu.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN specific_clothing sc ON (
        oc.product_id = sc.specific_clothing_id AND
        oc.product_type = 'clothing' )
    WHERE o.customer_id = '214';
```

Comment: Im getting a syntax error... have i done this correct  SELECT o.total, o.shipping, o.order_date
      ,oc.product_type, oc.product_id, oc.quantity, oc.price_per
      ,cu.first_name, cu.last_name, CONCAT(cu.address1, cu.address2) AS address,sc.style AS item

    FROM order_contents AS oc
    INNER JOIN `orders` as o ON oc.order_id = o.id
    INNER JOIN `customers` AS cu ON o.customer_id=cu.id
    OUTER JOIN specific_clothing AS sc ON (
        oc.product_id = sc.specific_clothing_id AND
        oc.product_type = 'clothing' )
    WHERE o.customer_id = '214';

Comment: Just eye-balling it, it looks okay. What is the specific error? You can try walking backward commenting out 1 table at a time until it works, then you know where to focus (ie if you take out the OUTER JOIN part (and associated 'sc' column in the select clause), does it run then?

Comment: I got it working with left outer join. but if the oc.product_id = other i need to select a different table.. do i need a if statment?

Comment: Okay, I added that to the answer. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, missed the second part. I just added `LEFT` into the statement above. You would need to add another outer join to the new table with that condition.